# C# passing property of viewmodel into dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dispatcher, writeablebitmap

I have a method which updates the contents of a WriteableBitmap (FrameDataNew) which is a property in my viewmodel (VM):

```
    public WriteableBitmap FrameDataNew
    {
        get { return frameDataNew; }
        set
        {
            frameDataNew = value;
            OnProptertyChanged("FrameDataNew");
        }
    }
    private WriteableBitmap frameDataNew = null;
```

When I receive a new Bitmap from a gstreamer class I have written I update FrameDataNew in order to show the latest frame onscreen. the window is a simple Image control which has its source bound to FrameDataNew.

The following code works fine to do this in my event handler:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// BitmapCaptured event handler for when a new video frame is received from the IP source
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The originating source of the event</param>
    /// <param name="NewBitmap">The new frame in Bitmap form</param>
    private void PipeLine_BitmapCaptured(object sender, Bitmap NewBitmap)
    {
        // render to the screen
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            // check the existence of the WriteableBitmap and also the dimensions, create a new one if required
            if ((VM.FrameDataNew == null) || (VM.FrameDataNew.Width != NewBitmap.Width) || (VM.FrameDataNew.Height != NewBitmap.Height))
                VM.FrameDataNew = new WriteableBitmap(NewBitmap.Width, NewBitmap.Height, NewBitmap.HorizontalResolution, NewBitmap.VerticalResolution, PixelFormats.Bgr24, null);

            // lock the bitmap data so we can use it
            BitmapData data = NewBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, NewBitmap.Width, NewBitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

            // lock the backbuffer of the WritebaleBitmap so we can modify it
            VM.FrameDataNew.Lock();

            // Copy the bitmap's data directly to the on-screen buffers
            CopyMemory(VM.FrameDataNew.BackBuffer, data.Scan0, (data.Stride * data.Height));

            // Moves the back buffer to the front.
            VM.FrameDataNew.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, data.Width, data.Height));

            // unlock the back buffer again
            VM.FrameDataNew.Unlock();

            // 
            //NewBitmap.UnlockBits(data);
        });
    }

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "RtlMoveMemory")]
    public static extern void CopyMemory(IntPtr Destination, IntPtr Source, int Length);
```

Now I want to update my program to handle multiple pipelines and WriteableBitmaps so I can show several video feeds. The first thing I did was create a static utilities class so I can pass in the new bitmap (NewBitmap) and the WriteableBitmap (VM.FrameDataNew) I wish to update. This I then called as required when the new frame arrives:

The utilities class (just the code concerned with my question):

```
    public static class Utils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Inject the source Bitmap into the Destination WriteableBitmap
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Src">The source Bitmap</param>
    /// <param name="Dest">The destination WriteableBitmap</param>
    public static void InjectBitmap(Bitmap Src, WriteableBitmap Dest)
    {
        if ((Dest == null) || (Dest.Width != Src.Width) || (Dest.Height != Src.Height))
            Dest = new WriteableBitmap(Src.Width, Src.Height, Src.HorizontalResolution, Src.VerticalResolution, PixelFormats.Bgr24, null);

        BitmapData data = Src.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, Src.Width, Src.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        Dest.Lock();

        // Copy the bitmap's data directly to the on-screen buffers
        CopyMemory(Dest.BackBuffer, data.Scan0, (data.Stride * data.Height));

        // Moves the back buffer to the front.
        Dest.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, data.Width, data.Height));
        Dest.Unlock();

        // 
        Src.UnlockBits(data);
    }

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "RtlMoveMemory")]
    public static extern void CopyMemory(IntPtr Destination, IntPtr Source, int Length);
}
```

...and the way I call it:

```
/// <summary>
    /// BitmapCaptured event handler for when a new video frame is received from the IP source
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The originating source of the event</param>
    /// <param name="NewBitmap">The new frame in Bitmap form</param>
    private void PipeLine_BitmapCaptured(object sender, Bitmap NewBitmap)
    {
        // render to the screen
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            Utils.InjectBitmap(NewBitmap, VM.FrameDataNew);
        });
    }
```

The image no longer appears onscreen. Stepping through the code it looks like every time InjectBitmap() is called the destination WriteableBitmap is null? The code creates a new one in the first if statement but VM.FrameDataNew remains null?

I'm definitely at the edge of my experience with this so any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: The aim is to have an observable collection of WriteableBitmaps so I can handle several of these efficiently.

Comment: Have you implemented BitmapCaptured yourself using a custom video sink? Can you please publish the code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple: you don't assign the newly created object to the `FrameDataNew` property, so its value remains `null`.

Don't forget that in C# the reference type instances are passed by reference.

So in your method you're doing the following:

```
void InjectBitmap(Bitmap Src, WriteableBitmap Dest)
{
    if (Dest == null)
        Dest = new WriteableBitmap(/* ... */);
}
```

But `Dest` is just a local variable inside of your method - the method's arguments can be seen as method's local variables.

So you assign a newly created instance to a local variable that will of course be lost when the method returns.

What you need here is a `ref` parameter:

```
void InjectBitmap(Bitmap src, ref WriteableBitmap dest)
{
    if (dest == null)
        dest = new WriteableBitmap(/* ... */);
}
```

Note that I changed the parameter name casing to match the C# style guide.

However, this won't work for properties, so `InjectBitmap(NewBitmap, VM.FrameDataNew)` won't compile if `FrameDataNew` is a property.

You could make the `FrameDataNew` to a field, but having a non-private mutable field is a bad idea.

You could use a temporary local variable, but it's somehow ugly:

```
var copy = VM.FrameDataNew;
InjectBitmap(NewBitmap, ref copy);
if (copy != VM.FrameDataNew)
    VM.FrameDataNew = copy;
```

I would rethink your design so that you don't need all that stuff.

By the way, having multiple calls to `Dispatcher.Invoke` in a multithreaded environment (especially if the invoked methods are slow, and yours are) will drop your app's performance and make the UI unresponsive.

Comment: Thankyou for your comments, the question is answered i guess :) I started to progress the project anyways and instead of a WriteableBitmap I pass in an ObservableCollection<WriteableBitmap> and the channel number, it worked fine for that approach so I probably would have got to that stage without needing to ask the question which is ironic. With regard to the performance I will keep an eye on the responsiveness when I have the number of channels I want and address it there. Thanks again.